# Spring annotation attribute setting with method invocation

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations, spring-data-jpa

I've got the spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
InfrastructureContextConfiguration
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {...}
```

I wish to set the `entityManagerFactoryRef` attribute of the `@EnableJpaRepositories` with `entityManagerFactory().getObject()` invocation.

Can I do that and how if it is allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. The attribute has to be resolvable at compile-time, and your bean (and its `getObject()`) aren't available until not only runtime but until after Spring has initialized the `InfrastructureContextConfiguration` bean.